# Post custom permalink results in 404 for archive page

Tags: posts, permalinks

I have set the following custom permalink structure (for my blog):

```
/news/%postname%
```

When I browse to `/news` I was expecting for the `archive.php` template to be served up, unfortunately, I'm presented with a 404.

My rewrite is working properly since I can view all posts such as `/news/my-post-title`.

How can I make it so that my "archive.php" is served up when browsing to `/news`, currently I have to create a dummy News page which is of course what I don't want.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I have set my Category Base and Tag Base permalinks as follows:

```
news/categorized
news/tagged
```

Browsing to `/news/categorized/test` triggers the `category.php` template and browsing to `/news/tagged/test` brings me to the `tag.php` template.

I still have no luck in triggering the `archive.php`.

Comment: is news a custom post type? or just the page for your blog?

Comment: This is just for built-in posts, not a custom post type. For some reason, custom post types seem to handle this just fine.

Comment: Do you have a page called news?

Comment: I don't have a page called "news". It's the whole point that I don't have to create "dummy" pages. I was expecting that my "archive.php" would be triggered instead.

Comment: if you browse to news/archive does it work?

Comment: No sorry. That doesn't work. Never heard of that either, do you have some documentation or reference for that? I don't think that should at all.

Comment: I was going on that the news/categorized and tagged returned the correct templates.

Comment: I think there is something odd on your end. Going to 'news/categorized' should be a 404. As far as I'm aware, you can only view a taxonomy by specifying a term such as 'news/categorized/term'. I still haven't solved my issue though...

Comment: I'm only talking about your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the Post type object settings in the `init` action and register the proper values for the archive and rewrites:

```
add_action('init', 'my_init');

function my_init()
{
   $args = objectToArray( get_post_type_object('post') );

   $args['has_archive'] = 'news';
   $args['rewrite'] = array(
      'slug' => 'news',
      'with_front' => FALSE,
   );

   register_post_type('post', $args);
}

function objectToArray( $object )
{
   if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
   {
      return $object;
   }

   if( is_object( $object ) )
   {
      $object = get_object_vars( $object );
   }

   return array_map('objectToArray', $object);
}
```

By specifying the `has_archive` and the `rewrite` values for the Post type object it's possible to force Wordpress the same behavior as one would do for Custom Post types.

Wordpress should now pick up the `archive.php` template when browsing to `/news`.

The only clumsy thing about this is of course that `get_post_type_object` returns an object version of the array that `register_post_type` takes as a parameter, hence the `objectToArray` helper function.

Comment: Unfortunately, this removes the ability to insert any new posts as well (in the wp-admin section), not able to create new posts or see any existing posts.  That whole section is gone now, only have the ability to edit/add Categories and Tags.

Comment: @SolomonClosson You are correct. This seems to have been the case since WordPress 4.8 (haven't tested further back though). Not sure what is causing this. I have created a new question but no feedback as of yet: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287065

Answer (score 0):

In case you  want archive page like /news, need custom slug after archive page like /news/latest and post detail page like /news/latest/%postname%, Below is code that helps me..

add this code to function.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_news' );
function create_news() {
register_post_type( 'news',
    array(
           'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'News',
            'singular_name' => 'News',                
          ), 
          'taxonomies' => array( 'category'),
          'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%latest_tag%', 'with_front' => false ),
          'has_archive' => 'news'
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy(
         'latest_tag',
         'news',
         array(
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'latest', 'with_front' => false ),
          )
      );
}
```

after that, put below code in same function.php..

```
function custom_slug_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'news' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'state_tag' );
        if( $terms ){
           return str_replace( '%latest_tag%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
  }
   return $post_link;
  }
 add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_slug_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

There is no need to add 'has_archive' as true, instead you can use custom post slug name over there and wordpress will go to archive.php..
After all that, **Do not forget to go settings->permalinks and click on save button :)**

Answer (score 0):

Re-registering the post type was causing me errors so instead you can filter the "args" on post creation (as opposed to recreating the whole post type).

```php
add_filter('register_post_type_args', function($args, $type) {
    if ($type === 'post') {

        $args['has_archive'] = 'news';
        $args['rewrite'] = array(
            'slug' => 'news',
            'with_front' => FALSE,
        );
    }
    return $args;
}, 10, 2);
```

Again, you still need to go settings->permalinks and click save.

You can see the filter in action here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/fcd890e54625d165c853825cdd4a44d17afd2acd/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php#L386

Hook documentation here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
register_post_type('post', $args);
```

to

```
register_post_type('news', $args);
```

and it works really fine!