# change default post archive page link

Tags: posts, permalinks, archives

I can't figure how to change the default post archive link.

I've got few custom post types (for instance video_news, slug video), if I type www.blogname.com/video I get the archive.php. And every post of custom post type 'video' have the structure www.blogname.com/video/post-title.

I've also specified the category base url as 'categories', so that www.blogname.com/categories/video/category-name

Fine

The problem is: how can I replicate this behaviour with the default post ('post') type?

I would like to use 'articles' so for instance: www.blogname.com/articles/ should open the archive.php page for 'post' type, and every post url should be www.blogname.com/articles/post-title.

Now if I change the permalink structure it changes everything.

So I get www.blogname.com/articles/categories/video/category-name (if I use the ''with_front' i get www.blogname.com/video/post-title, but the category permalink is wrong)

Can't understand how to change only the default post archive page link (and structure)

Comment: This helped me out:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43231/post-custom-permalink-results-in-404-for-archive-page/44128#44128